# How to do IMU and camera "sensor fusion" tracking?

Tags: imu, cameras, sensor-fusion

I have some 50ms latency cameras at hand and a  800Hz IMU (gyro+accelerometer+magnetometer). I would like to know how exactly how I should do a sensor fusion of such an IMU and camera to fix the positional data from the IMU positional drift. I'm not able to find much resources online.
The reason is that I don't want to go with just a camera  due to its 50ms latency.
​

The optical markers for the camera can be LEDs, ORB-SLAM data or AruCo markers which I currently use and which add another few ms latency to the camera tracking.
​

Maybe there is even an existing library or documented implementation I can use?
​

Answer (score 1):

The easiest platform for a multi-modal sensor fusion is a continuous-time trajectory model. Please have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr) and related papers. I believe that it should be state of the art implementation of what you are looking for.

Temporal difference between sensors can be estimated through a windowed trajectory optimization. Asynchronicity as well.